# (ngModelChange) does not fire when I remove all values or paste values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angular-ngmodelchange

The `(ngModelChange)` event does not fire when I clear all values from input field by using `Ctrl.A` or paste a value into it.

```html
<input pInputText (ngModelChange)="IsElementDataMissingForMultiValue(languages.TranslationValue)"  
    [(ngModel)]="languages.TranslationValue" type="text" />
```

```
function Controller()
{
    function IsElementDataMissingForMultiValue(value)
    {
        alert(value)
    }
}
```

The `(ngModelChange)` event triggers when I remove values one by one or add values one by one. But it does not trigger when removing all values by using `Ctrl+A` or pasting values by using `Ctrl+V`.

Comment: What browser? .

Comment: @gu Internet explorer

Comment: Did you check all required polyfills are installed? https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
Have you tried in Chrome, Firefox?

Comment: But I  have tested in IE 11 and IE edge. it's does not working @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Might be a bug that only occurs in IE/Edge. Before you create a bug report ensure the required polyfills are installed.

Comment: ngModelChange is working good. But it's only it does not working when clear all values by using ctrl+a @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: OOPS! I have missed something here. I have fount it now

Comment: Would be helpful for others that run into this issue to know how you fixed it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have answered it. it's my mistake. thanks for your time.

Comment: Weird. I wouldn't expect this change to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my mistake.

The problem occurred when I does not assign `$event` to `ngModel` object in some event's

This below code does not working

```
(ngModelChange)="IsElementDataMissingForMultiValue(languages.TranslationValue)"
```

But the below code working like a charm!.

```
(ngModelChange)="languages.TranslationValue = $event; 
IsElementDataMissingForMultiValue(languages.TranslationValue)"
```

I hope this may be helps others.

Comment: I guess what you actually should have changed is `(ngModelChange)="IsElementDataMissingForMultiValue($event)"`