# ngModelChange is not getting triggered when I do copy paste

Tags: angular7

When I paste the `cardnumber` for the first time, `ngModelChange` gets fired up but if U manually enter the `cardnumber` and then try to paste the value in the field, the `ngModelChange` is not getting fired from UI

```
<input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber"
#cardNumber="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="paymentModel.cardNumber" pattern="[0-9]*" 
placeholder="Card Number *" [maxlength]="cardLength" required (ngModelChange)="updatePaymentInfo();updateCardType();encryptCreditCard();">
```

when I copy paste the `cardnumber` for second time, my `ngModelChange` should be fired up from UI.

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="cardNumber" id="cardNumber"
                                #cardNumber="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="paymentModel.cardNumber" pattern="[0-9]*" 
                                placeholder="Card Number *" [maxlength]="cardLength" required (ngModelChange)="updatePaymentInfo();updateCardType();encryptCreditCard();">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(ngModelChange) does not fire while remove all values or paste values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079840/ngmodelchange-does-not-fire-while-remove-all-values-or-paste-values)

Comment: i have trired the above but ended up with no luck :-(